# How to transfer listview items to java database in JavaFX?

Tags: java, listview, jdbc, javafx, netbeans-8

I have a problem transferring listview items from a listview to a SQL database on netbeans using javaFX.

Here is a method that is called when you click the button to add to the listView items to the database (Add Order). I need all the items in the listview to be written to a column.

```
 private static void insertColl(){
    try{
        stmt = conn1.createStatement();
        String description = listView.getText();
        String query = " insert into ORDERS(DESCRIPTION)"
        + " values (?)";

    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn1.prepareStatement(query);

    preparedStmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlExcept){
        sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is what our javafx project looks like, the listview in question has an arrow pointing next to it.
Apologies if I am not using the correct terminology, as I am new to this. Thank you for your help.
 [image]

Comment: can you please post your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how PreparedStatement work, you should to set your paremetres to your statement ;

```
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn1.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setString(1, description );//<-------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add to the PreparedStatement the values, and try with executeUpdate().

Also, you are not using the first Statement.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStmt=conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(query);

preparedStmt.setString(1, description);

preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```